# Best way to cover main water supply valve into house

Tags: plumbing

What is the best way to cover exterior pvc pipe where shutoff valve is that leads into a house? I was thinking about down the line when it will be time to winterize.[image]

Comment: Cover in what sense?  Is this pipe outside and exposed or inside and exposed.  And - you're not talking about permanently covering the main shutoff, are you?  Because that would be very unwise.

Comment: Exterior pipe. I mainly wanted to cover pipe itself to prevent freezing.

Comment: This isn't an incoming supply line is it?

Comment: Yes, it is incoming line.

Comment: A photo would be helpfully here, I have used Styrofoam on several occasions where I had to bring the main up outside the home. If it is going into an unheated space like a garage be prepared to add some heat tape or let the water trickle when temps get below 27F.

Comment: I've added a picture.

Comment: The *best way* to cover is it is to use a few feet of dirt: bury it below the frost line. I'm guessing you're looking for something that doesn't require major work though.. You talk about winterizing -- do you mean you intend to shut the water off over the winter? What's this supplied from? What's the winter low temperature (or where is this)? What's the lowest temperature while you want to have running water?

Comment: Water is supplying house I am living in. Supplied by county. Live in central ga-The lowest temperature it normally gets is in 20's.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a plastic valve box (with lid) of the appropriate size. Cut a slot in one end to slip over the horizontal run of PVC that goes into the brick wall. This will protect the pipe from string trimmer, mower, and other damage of that type. These boxes are usually an unobtrusive color and will cover the white pipe.

Inside the box would put foam tubing insulation around the pipe and cram that into the hole in the brick wall surrounding the pipe. I would put flexible sheet insulation around the inside of the box above ground and also under the top, but maybe not along the wall next to the brick wall to allow heat to flow from the ground and from the brick wall.

**EDIT**
[Plastic valve box](http://www.homedepot.com/p/DURA-12-in-x-17-in-x-12-in-Deep-Rectangular-Valve-Box-in-Black-Body-Green-Lid-120/203473554?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CTHD%7CG%7C0%7CG-BASE-PLA-D26P-Plumbing%7C&gclid=Cj0KCQjwkZfLBRCzARIsAH3wMKray2SvfacFd_D01fGkO1hSzyVrWxo9Ubgy2DHWIApRz0e7qAb6v2oaAvfCEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Comment: Thanks for info. Could you post a picture of a valve box like the one you are talking about?

Comment: @dwhorne see edit. Valve box 12" x 17" x 12".